# camera does not work with opencv but does work with streamer

Tags: python, opencv, camera

Im trying to use beaglebone with a usb camera using opencv and python.
Im having trouble capturing the image. However the commandline tool streamer seems to work.
For python I get:

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
>>> cap.read()
libv4l2: error dequeuing buf: No such device
VIDIOC_DQBUF: No such device
```

However from the command line I can do the following and it works fine:

```
streamer -f jpeg -o image.jpeg
```

There is a /dev/video0
And when I use lsusb I see the camera as

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1908:2310 GEMBIRD
```

Any suggestions on how to get the camera to work with cv2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this camera is very low rez and I had to specify that it was 320x240 as opposed to the default of 640x480.  It just so happens that streamer was 320x240 by default anyway so it worked by default.

Here is the code.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3,320)
cap.set(4,240)
status,image = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite("current.jpg", image)
```